# Reading a File and String Equality Problem

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want the following following node.js program to read a file and print out "Login failed." if the text in the file is "Login failed." however the "`if (data == "Login failed.") {`" line fails to return true and the program prints out "Login succeeded." I'm using "CentOS release 5.5 (Final)" Linux distribution. Any idea as to what's up? Thanks!

```js
BASEPATH = '/home/wz3chen/node/';

fs.readFile(BASEPATH  + 'node.js/' +  "loginLog",  function (err, data) {
    console.log("DATA:" + data);
    if (data == "Login failed.") {
        console.log('Login failed.');
    } else {
        console.log('Login succeeded.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Both answers work, sucks that I can't choose to have multiple accepted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-line text files in Linux usually end in a new line.

It's not clear whether you're including `fs`, so here is the code that works for me:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    BASEPATH = '/home/jim/bin/';

fs.readFile(BASEPATH  + "loginLog", function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("DATA:" + data);

    if (data == "Login failed.\n") {
            console.log('Login failed.');
    } else {
            console.log('Login succeeded.');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The "data" variable passed to your callback is of type [`Buffer`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.4/api/buffers.html), which apparently doesn't cast to a string when comparing to a string.  You also probably have a newline at the end of your file, so trim it.  Try this instead:

```js
if (data.toString().trim() == 'Login failed.') {
  // ...
```

**[Edit]**

As @Jim Schubert mentions in his comment, the `data` argument will be a String if you specify the character encoding in your call to `readFile`, so you could also do this:

```js
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  if (data.trim() == 'Login failed.') {
    // ...
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the type as `Buffer`.  `data` is supposed to be `Buffer` only when an encoding isn't supplied (which the OP isn't supplying).  However, using non-strict equality (`==`) instead of strict equality (`===`) will compare `Buffer` to a `string` properly. At least, it does in node v0.4.8.